# API Cost for commentThreads?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to determine the cost of a commentThreads request (GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads)

I don't seem to find 'commentThreads' listed in the YouTube Data Api Quota Calculator (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

Anyone know how much each commentThread request costs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who finds this, it's not listed in the quota cost calculator, but on the documentation page for commentThreads: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#part

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find it in the documentation, but it seems that commentThreads are a resource only available to application with the "youtube partner" scope, so this is probably why it is not listed along with the other resources. When I tried to list commentThreads in my application I received an "insufficientPermission" error, while other resources work fine.